# Jquery DateTime Picker will not set time automatically

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view called edit and when the controller action returns this view, the datepicker will populate the correct date and time in the editor and calendar but the time is not being set at all in the sliders.

I am utilizing Trent Richardson's plugin.

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RunDate)
```

model.RunDate is of DateTime type

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //    $('.date').datetimepicker()({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" }); 
    $('.date').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
        stepMinute: 15,
        addSliderAccess: true,
        sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
    });
});
```

EditorTemplate

```
@model Nullable<System.DateTime>
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue) ? string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", Model.Value) : string.Empty, new { @class = "date" })
```

Comment: MVC without the actual language you are programming in is a pretty vague description....

Comment: I see, yes its asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now!  The time format in the editor template included seconds where as the datetime picker definition in the JS file did not contain the seconds.